# jQuery jPlayer - How to stop all players before playing a new one?

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I need to stop all other instances of jPlayer before playing a new one when i click play.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLVED

just assigned onclick function to the play trigger and the functions does:

```
function stopall(){
    $(".jplyrselectr").jPlayer("stop");
}
```

Comment: Nice - I used this to stop all jPlayers when opening a lightbox with a youtube video.

Answer (score 4):

Give all of your players a class (I think default is class="jp-jplayer"), then include the following "play" event handler in your initialisation options:

```
$("#jplayer1").jPlayer({
    ready: function() {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "mp3/track1.mp3"
        });
    },
    play: function() {
        $(".jp-jplayer").not(this).jPlayer("stop");
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    wmode: "window"
});
```

Comment: Thanks @jackocnr, this worked perfectly for me and didn't required any messy inline javascript.

Answer (score 1):

maybe `$("#jpId1, #jpId2, #jpId3").stop();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
$.jPlayer.pause(); // Pause all instances of jPlayer on the page
```

Reference: [Jplayer develpment guide](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-function-pause)

Or alternatively you can put this in the onclick or the click event function handler

```
$('[id^="jquery_jplayer"]').jPlayer("pause");
```

Comment: This does what you're asking, but then you have to fire the play event manually. Try just adding this to your jPlayer Obj: `$().jPlayer({play:function(){$(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");}});`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#jPlayer_ID').jPlayer("pauseOthers");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Actually it does EXACTLY what the OP asked, you just have to extrapolate... if you can't use what I've given, you need to take a step back. I'm assuming he knows how to watch for the 'click play' event he's talking about.

Comment: This worked for me. Additionally, if you want to choose where to put the play head postion in seconds pass a second integer parameter. This is straight from the documentation: `// Equivalent to "stop others", passing time as zero.
$("#jpId").jPlayer({
  play: function() {
    $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers", 0); // stop all players except this one.
  }
});`