# is there any method as stopOthers/resetOthers instead of pauseOthers in Jplayer?

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I implemented multiple jplayer instances on one page. However, I am not able to stop other players while one of the video/audio starts playing. I've tried to change below code in `jquery.jplayer.js` but it is working only in desktop browsers. On **ipad/phone** it is not working.

```
pauseOthers: function() {
            var self = this;
            $.each(this.instances, function(i, element) {
                if(self.element !== element) { // Do not this instance.
                    if(element.data("jPlayer").status.srcSet) { // Check that media is set otherwise would cause error event.
                        element.jPlayer("**stop**"); //element.jPlayer("**pause**");
                    }
                }
            });
        },
```

Comment: Try as suggested on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765533/jquery-jplayer-how-to-stop-all-players-before-playing-a-new-one by jackocnr